# JavaScript See if word contains ordered increasing/decreasing chars and repeat

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, algorithm, refactoring

2 codebase were written for checking string.
-The first is to confirm if a string contains 3 or more repeated characters in a string(111, ***, sss).
-The second if the string contains 3 or more ordered characters (123, efg, nml, 654). Ordered string checks if numbers or letters are in order of ascending or descending char.

Are there any edge cases I should worry about? Any way to optimize either? I want to keep these 2 algorithms  separate.

```
//code for consecutive repeated character 
const str= 'adsas111';//return true since 111 is repeated
let count=1;
        for (let i = 0; i < str.length-1; i++) {
          if(str.charAt(i) === str.charAt(i+1)) count++;
          else if(count <3) count =1
          if(count === 3) return console.log('It is repeated');
        }
```

```
//code for consecutive ordered character 
const str= 'adsa!"#32112s11'; // return true since 321 is repeated
  let ascCount=1;
    let descCount=1
    let len=str.length-1;
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length-1; i++) {
      if((str.charCodeAt(i)>=97 && str.charCodeAt(i)<=122) || (str.charCodeAt(i)>=48 && str.charCodeAt(i)<=57)) {
      if(str.charCodeAt(i)+1 === str.charCodeAt(i+1)) ascCount ++;
      else if(ascCount <3) ascCount =1
      if(str.charCodeAt(len--)+1 === str.charCodeAt(len)) descCount ++;
      else if(descCount <3) descCount =1
      if(ascCount === 3 || descCount === 3) return console.log('is in order');
      }
    }
```

Comment: The repeated sequence, is `!"#` considered as a sequence? Or is it any sequence of three sequential codepoints, when ex. `@AB` would be  a sequence to match?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Regular Expressions for algorithm 1? e.g. `(.)\1\1` ([Try it out!](https://regex101.com/r/kvcT97/1))

Comment: It is just a sequence of 3 or more letters or numbers only and assume that string is all lower case letters

Comment: To make it only check alpha numeric values added an check to see if the asci range is between a to z and 0 to 9.